# Pause GS Pro mission at every photo shot

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm working with DJI M600 and a custom camera that not from DJI. That camera requires a long pause at every shot, that means the M600 needs to hover for about ten seconds for every image. However the GS Pro software doesn't provide an option like "exposure time" that makes the drone hover for that long, every time the drone triggered the camera, it flies to the next point immediately.

So I'm wondering if there is any way in onboard-SDK or mobile-SDK that can stop the waypoint mission from GS Pro when the SDK detected the drone is hovering for a photo shot? I tried the dji.sdk.mission.timeline.TimelineElement.pause() but it seems not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

@xelmirage Hey, MSDK will support this feature in new version, currently it's under testing, please wait for the new Release, thanks

Comment: hi~ I checked the release notes of MSDK4.10(2019.05.15) and MSDK4.9(2019.01.28), there seems no such features added to the MSDK, is this feature added to the MSDK or still in test?

Comment: did you try this? WaypointActionType.Stay https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/Missions/DJIWaypoint_DJIWaypointAction.html?search=waypointactiontype&i=0&#djiwaypoint_djiwaypointactiontype_inline

Comment: thank you for your help,  what I want to do is creating the mission using the official GSPro app and intervening using the SDK, but the class WaypointAction seems not capable of dong this for me.